# Angular replaces variables after PHP parses them

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, smarty

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html ng-app="exampleApp">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var exampleApp = angular.module('exampleApp', []).config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[').endSymbol(']]');
});

exampleApp.controller('CreationController', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.creations = [
        {id:0,name:'aaa'},
        {id:1,name:'bbb'}
    ];
}]);

        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="CreationController">
        <?php
            $arr = [
                'a','b'
            ];
        ?>
        <div ng-repeat="creation in creations">

            <?php $a = "[[creation.id]]"; echo $arr[$a]; ?> // doesnt work
            <?php $a = "[[creation.id]]"; echo $a; ?> // shows 0 and 1 in next iteration - correct
          <?php echo $arr[0] . $arr[1]; ?> // works
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that:

`<?php echo $a = "[[creation.id]]"; ?>`

Displays `string(15) "1"`, because PHP parses the variable before angular replaces its variables.

How do I do this?

Comment: Try `{$externalArray.$id[0]}`

Comment: Doesnt work either. I now checked it with plain php without smarty - same issue.

Comment: are you sure `$id` has a value? can you show the code where it is being set?

Comment: Check out my edit, that's plain php. I am sure $id has a value, displaying just {$id} shows correct result.

Comment: Or `{$externalArray.$id.0}`

Comment: var_dumping $a in my edit shows `string(15) "0"`

Comment: 15 signs? It seems like php parses variable before angular changes it.

Comment: That is not the way to use angular. Make an api and call that for your data. Don't pregenerate values with PHP in the DOM.

Comment: So you want to have angular act before php? That's not possible, the php is rendered server side, angular is client side.